# how to use Neo4jImport tool to import hundred of files, on neo4j v2.2.0-RC01?

Tags: neo4j

I have hundred of files downloaded from Hive, their schema are consistent. I have tried to import one file, which contains 3M nodes, use the v2.2.0's new feature,Neo4j-import tool, to import it. It' pretty fast.

This is my command

```
Neo4jImport.bat --into ../data/weibo.db --nodes:User "c:\000023_1-hearder.csv,c:\000023_1.csv" --delimiter "TAB"
```

Adhering to the command usage, if I need to import multiple homogeneous schema files, I should use this:

```
Neo4jImport.bat --into ../data/weibo.db --nodes:User "c:\1-hearder.csv,c:\1.csv,c:\2.csv,c:\3.csv,c:\4.csv..." --delimiter "TAB"
```

What if I have hundred or thousand of small-partitioned files to import, should I cascade their file names? Or Is there any error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concat the files if they all have the same structure. And then zip them so they are smaller. That's what I would do.

Otherwise, yes have a file name with incremental number.

You can use a powershell/cmd script with a for loop to concatenate the file names into a one string. Although that might give a problem with the command-line length.

Comment: so, what do you mean "have a file name with incremental number" ? I do have some files whose file names like "000001","000002","000003" ..."000100". will the Neo4jImport tool enumerate all of them in my folder automatically?

Comment: No use a for loop in your batch file